# How to pass get-parameter to backing bean in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, parameter-passing

I have a get-parameter with name `controller`. When I try to pass it (with `propertyChangeListener`) to my backing bean I get `null` instead of the real value of that parameter:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg['mail.send']}" styleClass="mailbutton" action="#{mailSender.sendMail}">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{mailSender.controllerName}" value="{#param.controller}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

So, I have two questions:

1. What is the proper way to set bean property with a get-parameter value? 
   Actually, I've already get the value from `ExternalContext#getRequestParam` but maybe there are some other solutions.
2. More interesting question: why propertyActionListener didn't work here? What does it do actually? (again I have some thoughts about it but it would be nice to read more comprehensive explanations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a `h:commandButton` fires a `POST` request, not a `GET` request. To fire a `GET` request, you need `h:outputLink`. To set a `GET` parameter, you need `f:param`. To set it as a bean property, define it as `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml` with a value of `#{param.name}`. More hints and code examples can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html).

Second, your code is invalid. The `f:setPropertyActionListener` value should have been `#{param.controller}`. And to get it to work, the `#{param.controller}` should **already be there** during the initial request. It does not automagically set the value in the subsequent request as you seem to expect. For that you need `<h:inputHidden value="#{mailSender.controllerName}"/>` instead.

Comment: @BalusC: from your answer I understand that I asked very unclear question and that's why you decided to answer at once for all its possible 'true' meanings. Thanks anyway, it's useful as usual.