# JSF: Submit Post-Form and append GET-Parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form, that has 3 buttons. (finish, save, cancel)

finish should end an task and navigate back to the task-overview.
save should save the changes made and navigate back to the **task-details**
cancel shouldn' save anything but navigate back to the details.

The problem is now for "save": I wan't to submit the form and call an actionListener to do the "saving". but then i want to pass an id to the "navigation outcome" of the button also

in plain html, it would look like this:

```
<form action="taskDetails?id=5" method ="post">
   ....
</form>
```

so all params are submitted using `POST`, but the id is then available via `GET`.

How can i achieve this with JSF Forms?

My button currently looks like:

```
 <h:form>
 ...
 <p:commandButton action="taskDetails" actionListener="taskEditBean.saveTask()" value="Save" />

 </h:form>
```

using f:params like this:

```
 <h:form>
 ...
 <p:commandButton action="taskDetails" actionListener="taskEditBean.saveTask()" value="Save">
      <f:param name="id" value="5" />
 </p:commandButton>

 </h:form>
```

are submitted using `POST` also...

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539437/how-to-pass-get-parameter-to-backing-bean-in-jsf)

Comment: @Promichel: Different Question. i dont need the id while saving, but need to pass it to the upcoming site.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess your concrete functional requirement right, this would be all you need:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{taskEditBean.saveTask}" />
```

with

```
public String saveTask() {
    // ... 

    return "taskDetails?id=5&faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This will send a redirect to the desired URL after POST.

Comment: I expected this solution (and already know that) but the problem is, that the navigation outcome actually depens on the "task" ("different" xhtmls) that is saved or whatever. So i tried to "avoid" the usage of the returnvalue, but having the correct navigation outcome in the xthml file. (Yes, i can pass it as a param, but this doesn't feel "right")